# Android Sliding Panel (all the screen)

Tags: android, animation, panel, sliding

I have to implement a new feature on a big android project. I have to add a sliding panel in an existing view.

How it's work (simplified) :
I have a main windows (designed in file1.xml) which can be divided in 3 parts :
    - ActionBar : A simple ActionBar
    - MainContent : An empty linear layout
    - MyWidget : An homemade widget (like a list of tab headers).

I also have a file (file2.xml) which define the (for exemple) ProfilePanel with a lot of different widgets.
This View is added as a child of the MainContent Layout in the first view when the user click on the Tab header "Profile".  (if some childs already exists in the MainContent Layout, we just remove them).

Finaly i need to implement the SlidingPanel (third schema). 
I need to implement this on the file2.xml like :

```
<!-- ProfilePanel -->
<LinearLayout>blablablabla</LinearLayout>

<!-- SlidingPanel -->
<com.java........MySlidingPanel>
    <Button />
    <blablablabla>
</com.java........MySlidingPanel>
```

This sliding panel must be in two part :
    - On top : just a partially transparent color (LinearLayout)
    - On Bottom : Some Widget in a LinearLayout.

When the sliding panel is opened (by pressing a button in the ProfilePanel), it have to scroll from the bottom to the top and take ALL the screen even the ActionBar and the MyWidget which are in the parent view.

Schema here : http://postimg.org/image/5aeqov8tt/

And to be honest i had looking for same question on internet, but all the time it didn't help me so much.

Have you any idea about, how to make this kind of sliding panel ?

Comment: Have you looked at [`DrawerLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html)?

Comment: Hi, yes but they have a handle and user can drag them manually. I don"t want these two behavior